# Time Lookup Table in C++11

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

I have a table keyed by time, e.g.

```
time | valA | valB
---- | ---- | ----
09:00| 1.4  | 1.2
09:05| 1.5  | 1.4  
09:10| 1.5  | 1.4
```

I want to store this in a data structure and query values as of arbitrary times. E.g.

```
asof 09:01, valA = 1.4
asof 09:06, valB = 1.4
asof 09:14, valA = 1.5
```

What is the best way of structuring this in c++11? Which std::chrono datatype should I use to represent my times. How can I develop a solution that supports time zones? E.g. the times listed in my table may be in US/Central time and I may want to query using Australia/Sydney based times.

Answer (score 0):

To support local times in different time zones with `<chrono>` I recommend [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source time zone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).  This library is built on top of `<chrono>`, and uses the [IANA time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) to manage time zones.

Also, to handle time zones, you will need to store more than just time-of-day.  You will need to store the entire date, as a time zone's UTC offset often varies with date.  I.e. `09:05 Australia/Sydney` doesn't really nail down a moment in time.  But `2017-08-16 09:05 Australia/Sydney` does.

Here is how you could create such a time stamp with `<chrono>` and the time zone library:

```
using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;
auto zt = make_zoned("Australia/Sydney", local_days{2017_y/aug/16} + 9h + 5min);
```

You can print it out like this:

```
std::cout << zt << '\n';
```

And the output is:

```
2017-08-16 09:05:00 AEST
```

If you want to find out the local time in US/Central that corresponds to this same moment in time:

```
auto zt2 = make_zoned("US/Central", zt);
std::cout << zt2 << '\n';
```

And the output is:

```
2017-08-15 18:05:00 CDT
```

`date::zoned_time<std::chrono::seconds>` is the type of `zt` and `zt2` in these examples, and that is what I recommend you store.  Under the hood this type is a pairing of `{date::time_zone const*, std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, seconds>}` (two words of storage).

Source code:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Documentation:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

Video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vwd3pduVGKY

Comment: Thanks Howard, your library looks great, unfortunately I am not able to install any additional libraries. I only have the standard library.